# checking a large csv file for matching ID's taking long time

Tags: powershell, csv

The below powershell is functioning properly- however it is taking a long time like 10 mins on a 50k line csv. I am sure I am making it work harder then it needs- I only need to match the ID column and then return the columns for each match. Any ideas of how to make this faster of more efficient?

```js
$ID = @()
$fname = @()
$lname = @()
$mname = @()
$streetadd = @()
$apartment = @()
$city = @()
$state = @()
$zip = @()


$Ids = @(0317,11432,1104,9999,1955)

Write-Host "PLEASE WAIT >>> "


Import-Csv C:\mycsv.csv |`
    ForEach-Object {
        $ID += $_."ID"
        $fname += $_."First Name"
        $lname += $_."Last Name"
        $mname += $_."Middle Name"
        $streetadd += $_."Street Address"
        $apartment += $_."Apartment"
        $city += $_."City"
        $state += $_."State"
        $zip += $_."Zip"

    }

    foreach ($Id in $Ids) {
        foreach ($elem in $ID) {
               # Write-Host $Id
                    if ($Id -contains $elem)
                                            {
                #Write-Host "Customer Exists!"
                $Where = [array]::IndexOf($ID, $elem)
                Write-Host $ID[$Where] $fName[$Where] $lname[$Where] $mname[$where] $streetadd[$where] $apartment[$where] $city[$where] $state[$where] $zip[$where] 
    }
    }

}
```

Trying the below code from answer below @Moerwald and getting no results-

```js
$Ids = @(1317,1132,110,9999,1955)
$rows = @(Import-Csv C:\mycsv-csv.csv |? { $Ids -contains $_.id})

foreach ($r in $rows) {
 write-host $r.id; $r.fname
 }
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use an array list, with every `+=` array operation a new array is allocated, when using standard PS array. Create array list via `New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList`, afterwards you can call `Add` method

Comment: Whats the delimiter used in your Csv file? `Import-Csv` default delimiter is `, `.

Comment: yes it is a comma

Comment: Can you post the CSV content?

Comment: it would look simaler to this: Student ID,OtherID,First Name,Last Name,Middle Name,Birth Date,,,,,,,,Street Address Line 1,Street Address Line 2,Apartment,City,State,Zip
1317,,a,b,c,6/11/2019,,,,,,,,1 5th dr,,,main,nv,55555
1132,,d,e,f,6/10/2019,,,,,,,,7 24th dr,,,duke,az,55555

Comment: Well there is no `id` field in your Csv file ... I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Ids = @(0317,11432,1104,9999,1955)
$rows = @(Import-Csv C:\mycsv.csv |? { $Ids -contains $_.ID})
```

`$rows` will be array of filtered rows. You can iterate over the array via:

```
$rows | % { Write-Host "$($_.Id)"}
```

`$_`  references a filtered row, andhas properties that corresponding to the column names.

`?` is a shortcut for the [where-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6#examples) cmdlet.

`%` is a shortcut for the [foreach-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6#examples) cmdlet.

**Update**:

This code works:

```
$s =@'
Student ID,OtherID,First Name,Last Name,Middle Name,Birth Date,,,,,,,,Street Address Line 1,Street Address Line 2,Apartment,City,State,Zip
 1317,,a,b,c,6/11/2019,,,,,,,,1 5th dr,,,main,nv,55555
 1132,,d,e,f,6/10/2019,,,,,,,,7 24th dr,,,duke,az,55555
 '@

 $csv = convertfrom-csv $s
 $Ids = @(1317,1132, 11432,1104,9999,1955)

 $rows = $csv |? { $Ids -contains $_.'Student ID'} 

 $rows | % { $_.'Student ID'}
```

This returns:

```
1317
1132
```

Here is the [link](https://tio.run/##bVBLS8NAEL7nV8whEoWp7aSJJYdiqkUoVD305kXW7JQs5sXutkWtvz1uYoMofpcZZr7HME19YG1yLoq29Q3M08Db2J3kysJqiY82Z@3qndLGwoMoGddi6O6VlAV/9zdK2xyWwjKesLGa2cJCSs3GwFpVDPTvNMRFI7QtXSbeKvvmSJ3Pk2o8mtIMUeALZng1JhqHE0qGBILYZUrt2lKoCqs9xh08ommIKJFx26kmv1QzCKNBJnevjOL9JAtSz/Mzs4c5ZHW1Z223ui5H3cQ3nr@S7j2Qnvc39RFAFLlCNIkwcUBK4vjCmej60HF7s@M1fEAvHjlX6w414D9fBj9fDj5h0BzhrGP/XbftFw) to the running version.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for but I am trying to wrap my brain around it- I have tried a foreach ($row in $rows) { $rows | % { Write-Host "$($_.Id)"} }                   ---But it doesn't appear to be working?

Comment: The `%`  operator acts as foreach over `rows`, the actual object is assigned to `$_`

Comment: Thansk for that- but I guess I just am not getting it to work- what would the foreach look like? foreach ($elem in $_) {}

Comment: `foreach ($r in $rows) { $r.Id; $r.fname}`

Comment: I updated my question with the code I have tried with 0 results